# Browser.msgBox(prompt) gives a timeout error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Browser.msgBox(prompt) gives a timeout error in Google SpreadSheet when the user does not press OK for a longer time.

I know I could use "toast()" , but with this option, the user will not be able to acknowledge the end of the execution and they might not know if the process has run or not.

What I would need is an option which does not timeout regardless the time until the user presses an OK button.

Comment: Why don't you use HTML page, and create a input element with button.

Answer (score 1):

When using `Browser.msgBox(prompt)` the script will pause at this line until the Ok button is pressed the script is still running and the 6-minute timer ticking away.

If you are just using this to notify the user that the script has finished and not as some input to the script I suggest you use the [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) as this will allow the script to end but remain on the screen until it is acknowledged by the user.